# php sort an array by value and for equal values, sort by key

Tags: php, sorting, array-multisort

I have an array

```
(0=>0,1=>3,2=>3)
```

I have to sort this array first by values, and for equal values , I have to sort by order of increasing key first.

I have tried to use multisort over the array_keys(SORT_DESC) and array_values(SORT_ASC) separately, but that gives me:

```
(0=>0,1=>3,2=>3)
```

but I want

```
(0=>0,2=>3,1=>3)
```

Comment: Yeah ... nuff said. `ksort` will do what you want.

Comment: `ksort` only sorts by keys, not by values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use simple callback to sort it. Using [`uksort()`](http://php.net/uksort) it will be:

```
$input = array(0 => 0, 2 => 3, 1 => 3);

uksort($input, function($x, $y) use ($input)
{
   if($input[$x]==$input[$y])
   {
      return $x<$y?-1:$x!=$y;
   }
   return $input[$x]-$input[$y];
});
```